# Electric Magnetic potential and Lorentz transform

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, gauge-theory

I have heard that the scalar potential and the magnetic vector potential in the electromagnetic four potential become the four vector by the Lorentz transform. Thereafter, the Lorentz transform
leads to gauge theory.

1. How do the four potentials become the four vector?
2. Is the Lorentz transform related to gauge theory?
3. Is gauge theory related to the development of the four vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar potential and magnetic vector potential are combined into a four-vector, $A_{\mu}=(\phi,\vec{A})$ which is a gauge field, and in the language of differential geometry, a 1-form. The Lagrangian of the field theory (i.e. Maxwell theory) is,

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$

where $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}$ is the field-strength tensor, a 2-form constructed from the exterior derivative of the potential. As you stated, it is a gauge theory with a $U(1)$ gauge symmetry. In gauge theory, the Fourier transform arises when attempting to quantize the theory. In canonical quantization we expand it as,

$$A_{\mu}(x)=\int \! \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\vec{p}|}}\sum_{\lambda=0}^3 \epsilon^\lambda_\mu(\vec{p})\left[a^\lambda_{\vec{p}}\,e^{i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}} + a^{\lambda \dagger}_{\vec{p}} \, e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}} \right]$$

in Lorenz gauge$^{\dagger}$; this is known as the '(Fourier) mode expansion' where the Fourier coefficients are promoted to operators which are used to construct the Fock space of the theory.

---

$\dagger$ The theory has a $U(1)$ gauge symmetry which can be viewed as a redundancy in our description of the system. States related by a gauge transformation are considered equivalent. Hence we employ this to our advantage, and choose a gauge fixing procedure which is valid providing that every physical configuration can be shown to satisfy it via  gauge transformation. In Lorenz gauge, $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your concrete reply . I could understand better.